# PHP Plesk - php errors log files missing

Tags: php, ubuntu, plesk

I've rent a vServer with ubuntu 20.04  and use plesk

When PHP errors happen, then no error log files are created in the log folder.

On my old vServer which has windows there wasn't such problem, the error file was created in `log/php_errors/websitename/php_error.log` but in linux nothing.

in the php.ini I have `log_errors = on`

I've seen several similar questions but they aren't helping

Comment: On my Linux server, using Plesk, the error logs are located in the `logs` directory, one directory up from the website root. So, something like `/var/www/vhosts/<domain.ext>/logs`.

Comment: yes this is exactly the path I'm looking in but nothing there

Comment: The logs probably can also be found in: `/var/www/vhost/system/<domain.ext>/logs`

Comment: Oh yes there they are, how can I change it to /var/www/vhosts/<domain.ext>/logs ? Please cerate an answer so I can accept

Comment: Yeah, I've had the same problem, and there is something weird going on there. I found that after a while, no idea exactly how long, the logs will be mirrored in `/var/www/vhosts/<domain.ext>/logs` automatically. I would wait a day and see it the problem resolves itself. Never got to the bottom of this problem.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks! If you write that as answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Linux server, using Plesk, the error logs are located in the logs directory, one directory up from the website root. So, something like

```
/var/www/vhosts/<domain.ext>/logs
```

Sometimes they don't immediately appear there, then they can also be found in:

```
/var/www/vhost/system/<domain.ext>/logs
```

I don't know why the logs initially don't appear in the first location.